# Stuck in terminal at Configuring Secure Boot

Tags: command-line, secure-boot

I am on Ubuntu 18. I was trying to install amd drivers.

A Configuring Secure Boot screen appeared in terminal and I am stuck on it.

[image]

Clicking ok does nothing, pressing enter does nothing.. what do I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + '*mousewheel down*' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> for those without mice) and a screen for typing password appeared.

I then typed password pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

retyped password pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and the installation continued.

Comment: You're the best

Comment: whenever it happened, I used to close the terminal. Thought it was just my system that got stuck. You have my respect...:D

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>, then you will have to type a password and confirm it. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Arrows to the left or right are selecting the OK, than just click ENTER.