# Terminal how to exit 'Configuring Secure Boot'?

Tags: command-line, package-management, virtualbox, secure-boot

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
While installing virtualbox it is asking to configure secure boot.
I do not have BIOS supervisor password and hence cannot configure secure boot.
I see no way how to exit this process.
Force closing Terminal causes issues with dpkg.

How can I safely exit the process?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is either your computer, so you can make password and configure, or get the owner of computer to do it for you.  also see this link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063282/stuck-in-terminal-at-configuring-secure-boot?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it is my computer that I bought used.
The seller is no more responsive as it has been more than a year since I bought.

Comment: Is bios password set or not made yet?  If not made/set then simple matter of going into bios to make one(write it down and remember).  If already set but you forgot then google your computer make and model on resetting bios.

Comment: You must do a search with your favorite search engine, you can reset the BIOS by removing the CMOS battery and shorting 2 pins on the motherboard.

Comment: On getting a new computer I usually just disable secure boot.  Saves this type of problem later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can simply add a password, in which case Ubuntu will use that password to sign kernel drivers, OR you can access your BIOS and turn off secure boot, which will turn off this message.